# How to retrieve text from formcollection object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The values in formcollection object are stored as Key-value pairs. But, suppose somebody uses "Id" as the value and "Name" as the text to populate a dropdownlist. In that case, how can one access "Name" from the dropdownlist using formcollection object?

To access the selected value, I know this code:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection formcollection)
{
   var value = formcollection["dropdownlistName"];
}
```

The above code will give the value which is "Id", but what if I need to retrieve "Name" and store it in a variable?

I am a novice; if somebody knows, please help. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post the drop down list text to the server, you can only sent the values. There are workarounds -- you can POST the data manually and add the dropdown text along with it. But the proper way to do it is to refer back the `id` from the source you filled the drop down list in the first place.

Example:

If you have a drop down like this:

```
<form id="someForm">
<select id="country" name="countryddl">
    <option value="1">US</option>
    <option value="2">UK</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Get the value in the controller and map it back to the source.

```
public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection formcollection)
{
   var countryId = formcollection["countryddl"];
   var countryName = countriesMap[countryId ]; // Assuming countriesMap is a dictionary with all countries mapped to its Id.

}
```

**Workaround**

If you absolutely must send the text along in the form, you can override the default behaviour on form submitting and post the dropdown text along with the value:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedOption = $("#CountryId option:selected").text();
    // Add the selected drop down text to a hidden field
    $("<input/>",{type:'hidden',name:'countryName'}).val(selectedOption).appendTo("#someForm");
    // now post the form 
    $("#someForm").submit();
});
```

Now you can get the selected text in your controller like this:

```
var countryName = formcollection["countryName"];
```

Comment: Is the workaround a less desirable method of doing this? If so, why?