# Post Dropdown values/keys using FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, formcollection

I have a form that posts to an action:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CheckDataVM vm = new CheckDataVM();
        vm.SerialNumbers = GetAllSerials();
        vm.CustomerNames = GetAllCustomers();
        vm.DateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        vm.DateTo = DateTime.Now;

        return View(vm);
    }       

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CheckDataVM v)
    {
        CheckDataVM vm = new CheckDataVM();
        vm.SerialNumbers = GetAllSerials();
        var s = vm.SerialNumbers.First().Text.ToString();
        vm.Channels = GetAllChannels(s);

        vm.DateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        vm.DateTo = DateTime.Now;

        return View(vm);
    }
```

In my Razor view, I have post:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CheckData", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SerialsForm" }))
{
    <div class="card-body" style="font-size: small;">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSerial, Model.SerialNumbers, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The view model is:

```
 public class CheckDataVM
    {         
        public string CustomersName { get; set; }
        public string SelectedSerial { get;set; }

        [Display(Name="Select a serial number")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SerialNumbers { get; set; }
    }
```

The dropdowns work, but when I submit the form the only thing I get back is the object name (SerialNumbers) as the key.

I want to be able to get the selected item from the dropdown list and pass this to the FormCollection in the Httpost of the Index action. For the life of me, I cannot get it to work!

I am expecting to see a key called 'CustomersDdl' and it's value. For example, if I had a dropdown full of countries and I pick England, I am expecting to see a value come back in the FormCollection saying England.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To send dropdown text to server you can use hidden field which you need to set before form submit in jQuery with dropdown text and then add extra parameter to your POST action with hidden field name. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930221/how-to-retrieve-text-from-formcollection-object-in-mvc

Comment: Why in the world are you using `FormCollection` instead of binding to your model? But you issue is that you cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `SerialNumbers` is). Your model needs a property to bind to (say) `int SelectedSerialNumber` and then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSerialNumber, Model.SerialNumbers, ...)` (and delete the pointless `@name = "CustomersDdl"` which fortunately does not change the `name` attribute`)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for putting me on the right track. I am now bound to the VM and edited code above. Although I am getting back the index and not the text. I have set the text option in Select list. Is it the case you can only get back the index, as I only want the text back...

Comment: You have not shown how you generate the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, but the `Value` property is what will be posted back (I assume you are setting the `Value` property to a numeric value, not the text you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value to postback is depending on how you create "SelectListItem", in your case it is in the method "GetAllSerials()"

```
  vm.SerialNumbers = serialNumbers.Select(serial => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = serial.id == vm.SelectedSerial ? true : false,
            Text = serial.Name,
            Value = serial.Name
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting back the text by setting the Text and Value to SerialNumber. I don't need the index, so can I assume that is ok?

Comment: Actually, you can set the same value to both "Text" and "Value"


vm.SerialNumbers = serialNumbers.Select(serial => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = serial.Name == vm.SelectedSerial ? true : false,
            Text = serial.Name,
            Value = serial.Name
        }).ToList();


So you will get the text instead of "Id".